# DVD drive spins up on its own

Tags: windows-7, boot, laptop, dvd

I have a problem with my Laptops DVD drive.

Early when I start my laptop with power button first screen is about starting BIOS and interrupting Startup the DVD drive rotates for once and computer gets started.

But now when I start my computer the DVD drive rotate  for two times for 1 sec because it is empty. When the computer gets started Windows welcome screen comes and DVD drive rotates again for a short time. When I click on start menu DVD drive again rotates. When ever screen lid is off I just put my fingers on touch pad DVD drive again rotates.

I don't know what is happening. This happens every time whenever I try to start Windows programs like NOTEPAD, WINDOWS MEDIA PLAYER, ETC.

Is there any way to stop this?

Comment: no, the  answers on that question does fix my problem

Comment: I'm guessing that's a typo in your comment.  Your question appears virtually identical to the proposed duplicate.  That question had a bounty to actively attract any and all answers.  Asking the same question again is not likely to attract different answers, just duplication of effort.  If nothing in those answers "fixes" it, it probably indicates that it is normal behavior.  Repeatedly asking the same question won't yield a new solution.